# how to merge two folders by batch cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have this folders and i want to merge in one folder

```
 - C:\1\a
 - C:\1\b
 - C:\1\c
```

how to merge this folders to

```
c:\1
```

and delete the original by using batch

Comment: Use `xcopy`. You can call that from batch, if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
robocopy /mt /move "C:\1\a" "C:\1" *
robocopy /mt /move "C:\1\b" "C:\1" *
robocopy /mt /move "C:\1\c" "C:\1" *
rd /s /q "C:\1\a"
rd /s /q "C:\1\b"
rd /s /q "C:\1\c"
```

Help:
[`rd /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726055%28v=ws.10%29.aspx),
[`robocopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=WS.10%29),
[`xcopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: The `/mt` switch won't work with `robocopy` versions earlier than the one shipped with Windows 7.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  Indeed that is true, but the OP did not indicate a version of Windows so I will assume the they are up to date. :)  My goal is to provide the **best** and **simplest** answer for the targeted problem.

Comment: That's your decision, of course. However, it usually is safer to assume that a system does not necessarily run the latest version of something, and provide a solution that works on a broader range of systems.

Comment: IMO, this is nos practical.. what if we want to merge 100 folders? Any solution that merges all folders on a directory?