# Merge two folders in python

Tags: python, merge

I need to merge two folders,

The folders are named 12345 and 12345_

How would I merge the two?

I have tried but I end up with '12345.'

```py
for file in files:
    subFolder = os.path.join(destpath, file[:6])
    if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
        os.makedirs(subFolder)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), subFolder)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588225/how-do-you-merge-two-directories-or-move-with-replace-from-the-windows-command

Answer (score 7):

If replacing the files in the destination directory, if they already exist, is acceptable, then since Python 3.8, this can be achieved easily with `shutil.copytree`;

```py
import shutil
shutil.copytree("src_root", "dst", dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

From the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src to a directory named dst and return the destination directory. All intermediate directories needed to contain dst will also be created by default.

> If dirs_exist_ok is false (the default) and dst already exists, a FileExistsError is raised. If dirs_exist_ok is true, the copying operation will continue if it encounters existing directories, and files within the dst tree will be overwritten by corresponding files from the src tree.

> New in version 3.8: The dirs_exist_ok parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple recursive function in pure python that merge a folder and its content into an other:

```
import os
import shutil

def merge(scr_path, dir_path):
  files = next(os.walk(scr_path))[2]
  folders = next(os.walk(scr_path))[1]
  for file in files: # Copy the files
    scr_file = scr_path + "/" + file
    dir_file = dir_path + "/" + file
    if os.path.exists(dir_file): # Delete the old files if already exist
      os.remove(dir_file)
    shutil.copy(scr_file, dir_file)
  for folder in folders: # Merge again with the subdirectories
    scr_folder = scr_path + "/" + folder
    dir_folder = dir_path + "/" + folder
    if not os.path.exists(dir_folder): # Create the subdirectories if dont already exist
      os.mkdir(dir_folder)
    merge(scr_folder, dir_folder)

path1 = "path/to/folder1"
path2 = "path/to/folder2"

merge(path1, path2)
```

Here the `folder1` is merged into `folder2`.

For every `folder1` elements, it check if the element already exist in the `folder2`, if so the element is replaced, if not the element is created.

In the end, the merged folder contains its original elements plus the elements of the other folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, which copies all the files from folder one to folder two so folder two will have all files from one and two:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess as sbp
import os

path=raw_input('Please enter a path\n')
fol = os.listdir(path)
p2 = raw_input('Please enter a path\n')

for i in fol:
    p1 = os.path.join(path,i)
    p3 = 'cp -r ' + p1 +' ' + p2+'/.'
    sbp.Popen(p3,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From python, you could also call `rsync`, which is made for this.

```
import subprocess

## define your paths
path1 = '/path/to/12345/'
path2 = '/path/to/12345_/'

## where to place the merged data
merged_path = '/path/to/merged/'

## write an rsync commands to merge the directories
rsync_cmd = 'rsync' + ' -avzh ' + path1 + ' ' + path2 + ' ' + merged_path

## run the rsync command
subprocess.run(rsync_cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: What does `-avzh` mean as an `rsync` argument?

Comment: **v** - verbose  **a** -  archive mode, which allows copying files recursively and also preserves symbolic links, file permissions, user & group ownerships, and timestamps **z** - compress file data **h** -  human-readable